# What does AES256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96 mean in relation to Kerberos?

Tags: encryption, aes, hmac, sha-1, kerberos

I'm not completely clueless as to what it means, but I'd like to understand it at a higher level.

The highest encryption type used by Active Directory domain controllers for Kerberos authentication traffic is AES256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96.

The first part: AES256-CTS. That's AES with a 256-bit symmetric key operating in Cipher Text Stealing mode. Where does the 256 bits of key material come from?

The last part: HMAC-SHA1-96.  I get that it's using a hash-bashed message authentication code, using SHA1 for the hash. But what does the 96 mean? An SHA1 hash is 160 bits...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Decoding AES256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96

- AES256 = AES using 256-bit key
- CTS = ciphertext stealing
- HMAC-SHA1-96 = HMAC using SHA-1 hash function with mac truncated to 96 bits.

The benefits of HMAC truncation are discussed in [FIPS PUB 198-1](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips198-1/FIPS-198-1_final.pdf), chapter 5.
For HMAC-SHA1 96 bits is very common truncation, used for instance by IPsec/ESP.

For figuring out what key material is used, it is decided by Kerberos. Please, read the appropriate standards.

Comment: HMAC truncation... Interesting!

Comment: It's actually in NIST Special Publication 800-107 http://dx.doi.org/10.6028/NIST.SP.800-107r1