# Kerberos Use of SHA-1

Tags: sha-1, kerberos

A lot of good information on Kerbero's encryption methods discussed [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11626/what-does-aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96-mean-in-relation-to-kerberos), but I there is a second question that arises.  Does use of SHA-1 in the overall algorithm weaken Kerberos?  If so, will security scanners potentially block certain Kerberos tickets that use it?

Comment: Which version? https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/admin/enctypes.html

Comment: Context is Windows Server 2012 R2, so Kerberos 5+

Comment: 5+ is a generic term. What is the lifetime of a ticket on your system?

Comment: It seems mainly used in HMAC with output size 96 bits. HMAC is pretty robust, even if used with a weaker hash function or reduced output size...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes But ( insert here a good [meme](https://www.meme-arsenal.com/memes/73cd8f9e77fa9af8c371849e22f31ee2.jpg)) it uses 96 bits. I think one should only consider that if the lifetime of the ticket is not indefinite.

Comment: Info only:  if we're talking Windows Server 2012 R2 here, then we're talking a default service ticket lifetime of 10 hours.